# How to manually uninstall/purge modules?

Tags: 7, installation

I have a module `Media: YouTube` which is being buggy when attempting to uninstall. I disabled it in the modules along with its dependencies, and when I go to the uninstall tab and perform the uninstall operation, it returns a blank screen. I go back to the module page, and it's still there (along with 3 other modules that need this one uninstalled first before the others can be removed).

Is there a general method of purging modules from the backend? I have full access to the server and database as well.

EDIT: Checked logs and found a PHP error:

> [Thu Jan 19 13:12:21 2012] [error] [client 192.168.xxx.xxx] PHP Fatal
>   error:  Call to undefined function media_youtube_variable_default() in
>   /var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/media_youtube/media_youtube.install
>   on line 19, referer:
>   http://vulcan/drupal/?q=admin/modules/uninstall/confirm&render=overlay

Sounds like it's just a badly written module?

Comment: Have you followed the procedures for solving the Drupal WSOD (http://drupal.org/node/158043)?  It sounds like you have a bigger issue than a buggy module.  At the very least, you need to get an error message to diagnose what the problem is.

Comment: Reading through your link, I checked my log files to find my edit above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is a known bug](http://drupal.org/node/1164184). Replace the module with the most recent DEV version, update, and then try uninstalling again