# How to manually uninstall a module?

Tags: 7

I'm trying to uninstall the "Browsing History Recommender" but I get the HTTP 500 Server error. I want to remove this module completely from the database and FTP.

I have been searching for a solution but no luck, I have also read this question.
[How to manually uninstall/purge modules?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20162/how-to-manually-uninstall-purge-modules)

Please Help. Thanks

Drupal 7
Ubercart 3

Comment: HTTP 500 leaves full error message in server's error.log - could you try and provide it to us?

Comment: @Mołot is error.log part of Drupal files? Would I have it on my FTP account?

Comment: Nope, unless your host made it available to you. Many do. If so, you will have public_html or similar directory for your web files, and next to it dir named like logs. If not, you will probably need to ask your provider - unless answer below is sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have access to ssh, use drush to disable and uninstall the module. If you do not have access, disable your module, set the status to 0 for the module name that you want to disable.

```
UPDATE system SET status='0' WHERE name='module_name';
```

And then you can manually delete the table "history_rec_user_map".

It however has two variables ('`history_rec_uid_watermark`' and '`history_rec_last_aid`') in the variables table. Use `variable_del` to delete them

To remove modules, you have to remove them from your server's modules directory (usually sites/all/modules/).

**UPDATE:**

To delete the modules blocks use `delete from block where module = 'MODULE'`

Comment: Thank You, it worked. but I'm still having the following error if i'm in the edit user profile page. I'm not sure if I should ask as a new question. see the following comment.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: history_rec_similar_nodes-block in block_form_user_profile_form_alter() (line 571 of /var/www/*ftp*/modules/block/block.module).
Notice: Undefined index: 144ad102b79a0a2e9351fdc1767d1615 in block_form_user_profile_form_alter() (line 571 of /var/www/*ftp*/modules/block/block.module).
Notice: Undefined index: uc_rec_similar_products-block in block_form_user_profile_form_alter() (line 571 of /var/www/*ftp*/modules/block/block.module).

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: Thank You so much. I ended up deleting all the blocks manually from the Blocks table. Thank you again. :-)