# Update.php with errors in multisite (WAMP)

Tags: multi-sites

I have 4 sites using the same features / modules and have the db main (general), and a "bd for each site." Sure, but the update modules / drupal core is made only once. During the execution of update.php I get the error:

```
An unrecoverable error has occurred. You can find the error message below. It is advised to copy it to the clipboard for reference.
Please continue to the error page
An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally. Debugging information follows. Path: http://LINK_OF_SITE.com.br/update.php?op=selection&token=ouRkHusqVcR48Xy0n-j8hc-C2pMOEc3ABwv7oMgHbzo&id=99&op=do StatusText: ResponseText: ReadyState: 4
```

What should I do? I'm using WAMP (localhost) with Apache (2.4.9) and PHP (5.5.12) and MySQL (5.6.17)

in the log, http://teste/mea/?q=admin/reports/dblog

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146
>   Table 'teste_mea.backup_migrate_sources' doesn't exist: SELECT * FROM
>   {backup_migrate_sources}; Array ( ) in
>   backup_migrate_item->all_items() (line 923 of
>   C:\wamp\www\TESTE\sites\all\modules\backup_migrate\includes\crud.inc).

Answer (score 0):

probably an inconsistant module state. try to disable the migrate module in the database.

```
UPDATE system SET status='0' WHERE name='migrate';
```

for more details see here: [How to manually uninstall a module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78692/how-to-manually-uninstall-a-module)