# Can't uninstall User Badges

Tags: 7, installation

How can I uninstall the [User Badges](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_badges) Module? I always get the same error when I try:

> Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to file_delete() must be an instance of stdClass, string given, called in...

Answer (score 1):

Up to Drupal 7 all modules and themes list is stored in `system` table with there `enabled (i.e. 1) / disabled (i.e. 0)` status. To Disable your module, set the status to `0` for the module name that you want to disable. Check simple MySQL query below:

`UPDATE system SET status='0' WHERE name='module_name';`

After running the above query, try emptying the cache tables. You can identify cache tables by table name starting with `cache_`. To make sure Drupal doesn't try loading from cache.

You can find more details about same on Drupal.org in [Disabling or enabling modules manually in the database](https://www.drupal.org/node/157632) Or check [How to manually uninstall a module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/78694/678) question.

Comment: It is not advisable to directly set the status in the db. If the module implements hook_uninstall then with direct sql query this hook is not going to run and you will ended up having garbage of data in your db.

Comment: @gulok, yes, you're right, but he will at least stop getting error. After that hook_uninstall can be called separately.